# How to Fetch a object from json

Tags: python, json, boto3

I want to fetch a object block from the Json object .

This is the Json object . i just want to fetch single block .

```
{
"widgets": [

    {
        "type": "metric",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 12,
        "height": 6,
        "properties": {
            "metrics": [
                [ "AWS/EC2", "NetworkPacketsIn", "InstanceId", "16" ]
            ],
            "period": 300,
            "region": "ap-south-1",
            "stat": "Average",
            "title": "17"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "metric",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 12,
        "height": 6,
        "properties": {
            "metrics": [
                [ "AWS/EC2", "NetworkPacketsIn", "InstanceId", "16" ]
            ],
            "period": 300,
            "region": "ap-south-1",
            "stat": "Average",
            "title": "17"
        }
    }

]
}
```

This is the code which i have tried . But no luck . could you tell me where to make modification.

```
import boto3
import json    
# Create CloudWatch client
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')    
response = client.get_dashboard(DashboardName='ritesh')    
body =response['DashboardBody']
r = json.dumps(body)
loaded_r = json.loads(r)
print(loaded_r[1])
```

I just want this part to be fetched

Expected Output

```
{
        "type": "metric",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 12,
        "height": 6,
        "properties": {
            "metrics": [
                [ "AWS/EC2", "NetworkPacketsIn", "InstanceId", "16" ]
            ],
            "period": 300,
            "region": "ap-south-1",
            "stat": "Average",
            "title": "17"
  }
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting blank output . if i change the index in the print . i am getting single character . i am looking to fetch the whole block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this,

```py
import boto3
import json    
# Create CloudWatch client
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')    
response = client.get_dashboard(DashboardName='ritesh')    
body =response['DashboardBody']
loaded_r = json.loads(body)
print(loaded_r['widgets'][1])
```

1. You don't need `r = json.dumps(body)`
2. `json.loads()` converts the response to a `dict` which you can navigate with each
3. you can check this by calling `type(json.load(body))`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use `json.load()` instead of `json.loads()` because the latter returns a string, that's why you're getting a single character if you print an index of it.

Secondly, remove `r = json.dumps(body)` line.

Then your json has only one dictionary `widgets` with a list of dictionaries.
Your print should specify this parent dictionary in order to be able to fetch the objects you want. Replace your print with this one:

`print(loaded_r['widgets'][0])`

Comment: I am getting this error   File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(loaded_r['widgets'][0])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: The json you provided is after which instruction, json.dumps() or json.loads()?

Comment: It should be json.load()

Comment: @py_saad That's right, I edited the answer. Thank you

Comment: This instruction    body =response['DashboardBody'] fetches the json from aws resource . this json when printed looks like the json mentioned above . so i want to extract only the "type" block from the complete json

Comment: if i change json.loads(r) to json.load(r) . i am getting following error .Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    loaded_r = json.load(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 287, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @RITESHSANJAYMAHAJAN I updated the answer, get rid of the r = json.dumps(body) line

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead,

```
print(loaded_r['widgets'][1])
```

As your JSON object is interpreted as a dict, with `widgets` as key and a `list` as value, of which you need 2nd index.
Also, this `dumps` code block seems redundant, I think this much should be enough.

```
loaded_r = json.loads(body)
```

Get rid of

```
r = json.dumps(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which i used to build a dashboard and update the cloud watch dashboard without erasing the previous widget .

The below code 
 1) accept the metric from the excel file . 
 2) Pull the information about existing widget in a Dashboard 
 3) attach the jason script required to add the new widget specified in the excel 
 4) append the new json script to the existing json script
 5) Update the dashboard .

```
import boto3
import json
import csv
# Create CloudWatch client
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

response = client.get_dashboard(
  DashboardName='my-dashboard'
)

#print(response['DashboardBody'])

file = open("sample.csv","r")
numline = len(file.readlines())

name="ritesh"
obj="ritesh-test"

count =0
file = open("sample.csv","r")
reader = csv.reader(file)


first = 0
for line in reader:
    if (first == 0 ):
         first = first +1
         continue

    No_Dash="""
    {
        "type": "metric",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 12,
        "height": 6,
        "properties": {
            "metrics": [
                [ "AWS/EC2", "NetworkPacketsIn", "InstanceId", "%s" ]
            ],
            "period": 300,
            "region": "ap-south-1",
            "stat": "Average",
            "title": "%s"
        }
    }"""%(line[0],line[0])

    if count == 0:
        Dash = No_Dash
        count = count + 1
    else:
         Dash=Dash+","+No_Dash


body =response['DashboardBody']
response = client.get_dashboard(DashboardName='ritesh')

#body =json.dumps(response['DashboardBody'])

loaded_r = json.loads(response['DashboardBody'])
for i in range(len(loaded_r["widgets"])):
    Dash = json.dumps(loaded_r["widgets"][i]) + "," + Dash

print(Dash)


test = """{
"widgets": [
     %s

]
}"""%(Dash)



print(test)

response = client.put_dashboard(
    DashboardName= name,
    DashboardBody= test


)
```